# Pandas Dataframe Explode based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one dataframe and I want to explode on all of the columns (A, B & C) only when values are of list type.

> ```
>                 A  B          C
>         [0, 1, 2]  1  [a, b, c]    
>            [3, 4]  1     [d, e]
>    {'foo': 'bar'}  1        NaN 
>  {'key': 'value'}  1         []
> ```

Expected Output:

```
                          A  B    C
        0                 0  1    a
        0                 0  1    b
        0                 0  1    c
        0                 1  1    a
        0                 1  1    b
        0                 1  1    c
        0                 2  1    a
        0                 2  1    b
        0                 2  1    c
        1    {'foo': 'bar'}  1  NaN
        2  {'key': 'value'}  1  NaN
        3                 3  1    d
        3                 3  1    e
        3                 4  1    d
        3                 4  1    e
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to split your dataframe into to parts for each column, the one to explode and the one to leave alone and then recombine them.

```
for x in df.columns:
    explode_columns = df[x].apply(lambda x: type(x)==list)
    df= pd.concat([df.loc[explode_columns].explode(column=[x]),
                   df.loc[~explode_columns]])
```