# How to stop getting NaN values when using str.split?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I use str.split and stop values in column returning NaN? I'm looking through a column and trying to split multiple dates into multiple rows which is working fine, however, rows that don't have multiple dates are returning NaN but I want these to be unaffected. Please see below - table before code:

| Event Date |
| --- |
| 2020-07-16 |
| 31/03/2022, 26/11/2018, 31/01/2028 |

```
df["Event Date"] = df["Event Date"].str.replace(' ', '')
df["Event Date"] = df["Event Date"].str.split(",")
df= df.explode("Event Date")
pd.to_datetime(df['Event Date'], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce')
```

Table after code:

| Event Date |
| --- |
| NaN |
| 31/03/2022 |
| 26/11/2018 |
| 31/01/2028 |

What I'm trying to achieve:

| Event Date |
| --- |
| 2020-07-16 |
| 31/03/2022 |
| 26/11/2018 |
| 31/01/2028 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Dataframe Explode based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71711858/pandas-dataframe-explode-based-on-condition)

Comment: you could to use fillna ath the end

Answer (score 1):

Your code works well:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['Event Date'].str.split(', ').explode(), dayfirst=True)
0   2020-07-16
1   2022-03-31
1   2018-11-26
1   2028-01-31
Name: Event Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: This gives me the error: ValueError: day is out of range for month present at position 1

Comment: Try to remove dayfirst=True

Answer (score 0):

Your code works just as you intended.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Event Date':['2020-07-16',"31/03/2022, 26/11/2018, 31/01/2028"]})
df
```

Results in

```
    Event Date
0   2020-07-16
1   31/03/2022, 26/11/2018, 31/01/2028
```

And after

```
df["Event Date"] = df["Event Date"].str.replace(' ', '')
df["Event Date"] = df["Event Date"].str.split(",")
df= df.explode("Event Date")
pd.to_datetime(df['Event Date'], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce')
```

The resulting pd.Series is

```
0   2020-07-16
1   2022-03-31
1   2018-11-26
1   2028-01-31
Name: Event Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```